# stl: не удаётся сделать emplace_back в вектор

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема:

Есть класс

```
class CSLE
{
public:
    // конструкторы
    CSLE(
        const int                           variablesAmount,    // кол-во неизвестных
        const borders_list_t&               variablesLimits,    // диапазон значений неизвестных
        const borders_list_t&               parametersLimits,   // диапазон значений коэффициентов
        const std::vector<std::string>&     variablesNames      // названия переменных
    );
};

// конструктор класса
CSLE::CSLE
(
    const int                           variablesAmount,    // кол-во неизвестных
    const borders_list_t&               variablesLimits,    // диапазон значений неизвестных
    const borders_list_t&               parametersLimits,   // диапазон значений коэффициентов
    const std::vector<std::string>&     variablesNames      // названия переменных
)
{
// тут формирую значения членов класса
}
```

Когда пытаюсь записать в вектор через

```
using sle_t = std::vector<CSLE>;
sle_t sleList;

sleList.emplace_back(2, { borders_t(-7, 7) }, { borders_t(-10, 10), }, variablesName[0]);
```

Получаю

> Error C2672   'std::vector>::emplace_back': no
>   matching overloaded function found
>   Error   C2784   'decltype(auto)
>   std::vector>::emplace_back(_Valty &&...)':
>   could not deduce template argument for '_Valty &&...' from
>   'initializer list'

Когда делаю с указанием класса (как при `push_back`), то естественно всё нормально.

Думал, что при `emplace_back` просто не надо указывать соответствующий класс и все

Comment: А конструктор копирования у  CSLE есть?

Comment: *"Когда делаю с указанием класса (как при push_back"* Как связаны push_back и указание класса? Можно сделать так: `sleList.push_back({2, { borders_t(-7, 7) }, { borders_t(-10, 10), }, variablesName[0]})`.

Comment: тут не видны члены  вашего класса, не понятно почему имя аргумента конструктора (variablesName) должна быть видна где то в другом месте, не понятно  формирует ли  { borders_t(-7, 7) }  обьект типа  borders_list_t

Comment: @Chorkov, нет, а он обязателен, конструктор копирования?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен, но лишние скобки - это не особенно лучше, если указать класс `CSLE(...)`

Comment: @Zhihar Это лучше, чем неработающий `emplace_back`. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен, но хотелось бы понять, почему таки не работает :)

Comment: @Chorkov, конструктор копирования ничем не помог - так же ругается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Что делать?**

Использовать `push_back` с фигурными скобками:

```
sleList.push_back({2, { borders_t(-7, 7) }, { borders_t(-10, 10), }, variablesName[0]});
```

---

**Почему `emplace_back` не работает?**

Простой пример:

```
struct A
{
    int x, y;
    A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

void foo(A) {}

int main()
{
    foo(A(1,2)); // работает
    foo({1,2}); // работает
}
```

Примерно так работает `push_back`. Тут все нормально.

А `emplace_back` - это шаблон. Сделаем `foo` шаблоном и посмотрим на результат:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {}

int main()
{
    foo<A>({1,2}); // работает, T = A (указан явно)
    foo(A(1,2)); // работает, T = A (компилятор догадался по аргументу функции)
    foo({1,2}); // не работает, T = ???
}
```

Вот что пишет Clang:

```
main.cpp:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo({1,2}); // не работает, T = ???
    ^~~
main.cpp:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
void foo(T) {}
     ^
```

Вызов `foo({1,2})` для шаблонного `foo` не работает, потому что компилятор не может определить тип `T`.

Он никак не может догадаться, что под `{1,2}` вы имели в виду `A`.

С `emplace_back` происходит то же самое, (из-за того, что у вас некоторые аргументы имеют вид `{ ... }`):

```
sleList.emplace_back(2, { borders_t(-7, 7) }, { borders_t(-10, 10), }, variablesName[0]);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Перед фигурными скобками нужно указать тип: `borders_list_t{ borders_t(-7, 7) }` и т.д.

Comment: Видимо, скобки нужны, так как `borders_list_t` - это что-то вида `std::vector<borders_t>`

Comment: @int3 Угу, перепутал `borders_list_t` и `borders_t`. Исправил.